# std::multiset<int> vs. std::map<int, std::size_t> for keeping multiple repeatable integer values

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I want to create a record that would hold the information about

- a) what kind of elements are present and
- b) the number of elements of each kind present

in a node of a tree. I would explicitly store this information only for the leaf nodes, while the information for the parent node can be obtaining through combining the information of all of it's children (e.g. child 1 has 3 objects of A, 1 object of B, child 2 has 1 object of A, 2 objects of C -- parent has 4 objects of A, 1 object of B and 2 of C).

I will be careful when requesting this information from the parent nodes not to first request, use and discard information for a child node and then for its parent node, but the *upward construction* will be a common operation. Other two common operations are directly derived from what I store: *is the object of kind X present?* and *how many objects of kind X is present?* and also **how many kinds of objects are present?**

Object kinds are represented as integers, and the object numbers are always integer values. What is the better choice (and arguments for the selected choice):

- use `std::multiset<int>`, and operate with `std::multiset::count()` and `std::multiset::find()` operations (easier union but duplication of elements, total distinct element count hard to obtain)
- use `std::map<int, std::size_t>` with the kind as a key and number of objects as a value (no duplicate elements, `std::map::find()` function present, size gives the correct number of object kinds stored, but accessing a non-existent element increases the size unintentionally)

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @larsmns I can not test them in a working environment (I'm in the middle of implementing a big thing, and this component will be used in yet unimplemented things and maybe things not in plan yet). And, I can not predict the exact ratio of operations, so I can not simulate a working environment. Thank you for the `size_t` though.

Comment: @larsmans Though I'm not a big friend of the "always profile without reasoning"-arguments, +1 for propagating unsigned types. There are usually much less situations where a signed type makes more sense than an unsigned one.

Comment: @ChristianRau: you're quite right, sorry about that. I thought the matter through and posted an answer; `map` and `multiset` can actually have different space complexity, depending on the distribution of keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To store a total of *n* items with *k* distinct values per your comparison predicate, an `std::multiset` allocates *n* binary search tree nodes(*). An `std::map` allocates only *k* (slightly larger) nodes.

You'd use `std::multiset` when two items can be considered equal by your comparison predicate, but must still be explicitly stored, because they differ in some aspect that the comparison predicate does not check. Also, iterating over a `multiset` generates each of the *n* items, whereas a `map` would generate each of the *k* distinct items with the count for each.

In the case where the items are just integers, go with `std::map`. Your "how many distinct items" query would then just be a call to `size`, which runs in constant time.

Your claim that "accessing a non-existent element increases the size unintentionally" is only true if you use `operator[]` to access nodes. [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) does not exhibit this behavior.

(*) The C++ standard does not guarantee that these containers are implemented as (balanced) BSTs, but in all implementations that I've seen, they are.

Answer (score 3):

What about a sorted `std::vector<int>`?  The operations you need can be satisfied as follows:

- *Is the object of kind X present?*  `std::binary_search`
- *How many objects of kind X are there?*  `std::equal_range`, subtract `.first` from `.second`
- *How many kinds of objects are present?*

  - `std::unique_copy` followed by `size()` of the copy, or...
  - use a separate counter, call `std::binary_search` before inserting into the vector

Advantages to this approach are cache locality (all your data is contiguous) and lower memory footprint compared to a tree-like structure.  Without knowing more about your data, I can't say for sure whether it would be faster or slower.  You'll have to profile it to find out, but I have a hunch this will perform better than you might expect.

The biggest tradeoff here is expressiveness.  The `std::map` approach probably does a better job of logically conveying what you're doing, i.e., a relationship between object IDs and a count.